# Parsing content from any url and showing in div in original form

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I am reading web page content in this way:

```
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);      // PLease dont suggest file_get_Content($url) I cant use due to some issue
foreach($xpath->query("//script") as $script) {
    $script->parentNode->removeChild($script);
}
$textContent = $doc->textContent;
```

And then

`echo $textContent;`

I am taking the response of this page into one div to show the result of `$textContent`.

But entire text is shown in single paragraph. Not as usual on the page.
I tried with 
`<pre>` tag. But it shows entire content in single line.

So how can I show it in original form as in webpage?

output currently:

```
Investor Herd Dynamics Want to start a startup? Get funded by Y Combinator. August 2013The biggest component in most investors'\'' opinion of you is the opinion of other investors. Which is of course a recipe for exponential growth. When one investor wants to invest in you, that makes other investors want to, which makes others want to, and so on.Sometimes inexperienced founders mistakenly conclude that manipulating these forces is the essence of fundraising. They hear stories about stampedes to invest in successful startups, and think it'\''s therefore the mark of a successful startup to have this happen. But actually the two are not that highly correlated. Lots of startups that cause stampedes end up flaming out (in extreme cases, partly as a result of the stampede), and lots of very successful startups were only moderately popular with investors the first time they raised money.So the point of this essay is not to explain how to create a stampede, but merely to explain the forces that generate them. These forces are always at work to some degree in fundraising, and they can cause surprising situations. If you understand them, you can at least avoid being surprised.One reason investors like you more when other investors like you is that you actually become a better investment. Raising money decreases the risk of failure. Indeed, although investors hate it, you are for this reason justified in raising your valuation for later investors. The investors who invested when you had no money were taking more risk, and are entitled to higher returns. Plus a company that has raised money is literally more valuable. After you raise the first million dollars, the company is at least a million dollars more valuable, because it'\''s the same company as before, plus it has a million dollars in the bank. [1]Beware, though, because later investors so hate to have the price raised on them that they resist even this self-evident reasoning. Only raise the price on an investor you'\''re comfortable with losing, because some will angrily refuse. [2]The second reason investors like you more when you'\''ve had some success at fundraising is that it makes you more confident, and an investors'\'' opinion of you is the foundation of their opinion of your company. Founders are often surprised how quickly investors seem to know when they start to succeed at raising money. And while there are in fact lots of ways for such information to spread among investors, the main vector is probably the founders themselves. Though they'\''re often clueless about technology, most investors are pretty good at reading people. When fundraising is going well, investors are quick to sense it in your increased confidence. (This is one case where the average founder'\''s inability to remain poker-faced works to your advantage.)But frankly the....
```

Comment: Show your response output

Comment: @NathanSrivi: I added the response output!

Comment: Please put without pre tag response

Comment: @NathanSrivi: Here is my code please review :http://codetidy.com/6796/

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are only getting the inner text (ie. textContent) of your HTML is because that's how textContent is meant to work. Instead, you want to get the innerHTML of your nodes, by changing your code to look like this:

```
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

libxml_clear_errors();

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);      // PLease dont suggest file_get_Content($url) I cant use due to some issue

foreach($xpath->query("//script") as $script) {
    $script->parentNode->removeChild($script);
}

$innerHTML = '';

foreach ($doc->childNodes as $child)
{
    $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
}
```

Now you can echo out `$innerHTML` as you please, it will contain all HTML.

Comment: thanks, but now this shows everything imcluding image, button and other things. I want to show only text content!

Comment: I think `$test = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", " ", html_entity_decode($text));` will help me. But here how to include new line character?

Comment: Please post your HTML input file to pastebin and post the link here.